# Is Web start Today a good website builder?

Tags: website-design, website-templates

I have a small business and i want to put it online so for that iam looking for website builder to build website for my small business. Some of my friends suggested me wix but some are suggesting me [Webs Start Today](http://www.webstarttoday.com/free-online-store-builder/) as it offers responsive web design and also provide shopping cart for ecommerce website building. please suggest me, should I go for Web Start today ?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Well, you have all kinds of possibilities, Wix, Webs Start Today, Wordpress with it's themes and much more but...think about it like this.

Can a program/web tool, no matter how good or how many people worked on it, dictate through it's templates what you like or need? I mean, sure, if it's a first, it would probably be a good place to start to figure out what you want and need for your business but no matter how hard they try, a computer can never outmatch a human at designing a website.

Each business needs it's own image, it has to resemble it's owner and the entire concept of the business. It's true that you need to target people online too but your website needs to be made as "human" as possible, in 9 out of 10 times customers will choose a product on the web based on it's website design ( UI and UX), the amount of effort and time they believe it's been invested in creating it. It gives them confidence that your products work and you are a reliable business.

Another thing that I do not approve of CMS platforms and themes like Wordpress is that the designer is trying to do a all-in-one-purpose website, therefore he ads a lot of things that you might not need, lots of plugins and that will increase the load time, will increase the space you need on your server and you will end up with way more than you need.

So, basically, my answer is that you can try all of them and see which suits you needs best (**but you should probably start with a Wordpress theme, since it's popularity, search engines see it better and your website will be indexed quicker so you'll be visible faster on the web**), it's basically opinion based due to every person's/business's needs and understanding of the CMS...but you will eventually end up hiring a designer/programmer and creating your own website.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Alin !  .. You are right but i don't have technical knowledge about website design or website building it will be challenge to me to build it in another way instead of using website builder that's why I am talking about website builder and many people i know they are getting good business and they also have website created by using website builder like Web Start Today. However, their costs varied with time but it doesn't matter if your business is growing. So i would like to know that if I have to go for website builder which one should i choose ?

Comment: Maria, if you really need to go for a website builder, I thing the wisest of choices would be the one you proposed, I just looked into this website builder and it looks pretty fine for a first. I would advise to go with a free plan and see how that goes. Like I said, Wordpress is the best at this department and you can buy a pre-made website for as low as 10$.

Comment: Also, i just checked the prices, this builder has a web shop plan of 25$ per month...in my country, a basic web shop can have a starting price or 350$...equivalent to 14 months of paying for the Webs Start Today services. On long term, you might want to consider hiring someone to create you a website exactly like you want it to be with the exact functions you desire ;) Think about it.

Comment: If you will ever consider Wordpress, a good shop for wordpress themes is http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress

Comment: There are some irrelevant tangents in this post. Secondly, what data do you have to back up your 9 in 10 "fact"? Thirdly, starting with WP because it gets "indexed quicker" is completely false. Search engines index based on content, not the CMS used. Fourthly, you even mention in your answer that this question is primarily opinion based, so please flag it as such instead of answering it next time. Lastly, there isn't always a need to hire a designer/programmer to create a website, it depends on the needs of the site

Comment: @ZachSaucier I am sorry to say but due to Wordpress's frequent update rate you can get a WordPress site ranking very quickly compared to a static website. Google has even gone on record as recommending WordPress for business sites. Also, when creating a website you might need to manually upload your own sitemap, send crawlers to your website via analytics.

Comment: Google has even gone on record as recommending WordPress for business sites [citation needed]

Comment: Downvoted because you said you don't approve of CMS like Wordpress and then encouraged the poster to use that very product.

Comment: @PieBie Matt Cutts interview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gscFgaMTm48

Comment: @Ryan Sure thing, I who work with different CMS platforms do not agree with Wordpress but for someone who barely knows what a CMS is, or how to get visible faster and never used these, what am I supposed to do, recommend something they clearly can't handle? I recommended WP for it's benefits, not for the downsides. I sad if you were to choose between WP or Wix and a designer, pick a designer. If you're not willing to hire a designer, pick the least bad option. Is this a bad thing ?

Comment: lots of misinformation in this.